# Custom php via ajax to set session value in Magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento, session

I have implemented music to play throughout the website in `header.phtml` using html5 audio tag and user has the option to click on an icon to mute the music. The action works in the following steps:

1) Icons are wrapped under forms whose code is given below:

```
<form method="post"  id="unmute_form" action="process_unmute.php">
<input type="submit" id="mute" name="mute" value="" style="background: url('music/mute.png')" />
</form>

<form method="post"  id="mute_form" action="process_mute.php">
<input type="submit" id="mute" name="mute" value="" style="background: url('music/speaker.png')" />
</form>
```

2) User clicks on mute icon and form is being submitted via ajax to an external php file to set magento session with the following code:

```
require_once ("../app/Mage.php");
Mage::app(); 
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMuted('true');
```

3) Form submission via ajax using jQuery:

```
$("form#mute_form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "musicFolderAtRoot/process_mute.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) { }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

The same logic i had already applied in a php project and it is working fine but in Magento process_mute.php file is not setting session value.

Any clue how i can call my php file from phtml file, i think my php file is unable to set session because of **placing php file in the wrong directory so it is inaccessible for session** (tried `root/folder` and `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/`)

OR

I need to create a magento module to have this simple session setting functionality (painful task for this small task)

Comment: You need to use start_session at the start of your ajax file..

Comment: you mean in process_mute.php file? it is using Mage:: and session is started already for Mage::

Comment: please please please let the user the ability to turn **on** the music if he wants to, don't turn it on by default

Comment: your ajax doesn't know that..

Comment: @OSdave it depends on client requirements bro.. if they ask i will turn it off by default

Comment: @Dieter you mean i need to start session in header.phtml file?

Comment: Please try to stick to MVC, it will cause you less pain in the long run. This needs to be in a controller which will give you full access to the Magento framework. Please also reconsider playing music on your store.

Comment: process_mute.php , on top of this file.. If that doesn't work, then I have no clue

Comment: @input i will have to make module for this small functionality, do you think it is a good idea? and about reconsideration.. bro client is always right so i think OSdave's idea is good turn music off by default but i agree eCommerce site should not have music.. will try to convince client for it..

Comment: @wakqasahmed it is good to have everything wrapped in a module, big or small it makes code reuse easier and you can turn them off, generally they are amazing. I use PHPStorm with magicento which auto makes modules for me, having anything outside of Magento just feels sloppy.